# Can the question list pages be prevented from being indexed by Google?

Tags: support, google, question-lists

Once in a while I find myself coming from Google Search to a Stack Overflow page like

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding-style?page=5&sort=newest`

Although the snippet on Google can look promising, in practice it's always a disappointment. And here's why.

1. These pages are changing quite fast. Often they don't even contain the words from my Google query.
2. Even if the words are there, the search result still is often irrelevant because the query words are taken from different questions. For example, if I'm googling for `foo baz bar`, I can get a Stack Overflow page that just lists one separate question about `foo`, one about `baz`, and two about `bar`. Not very helpful, as you can see.

Comment: What was your actual google query? I usually find Stack Overflow specific questions very quickly using Google.

Comment: `Allman style jscs`

Comment: To get around #1, use Google's cached view (which will show you what it looked like when Google last spidered it). This is a good search technique for any rapidly-changing page.

Comment: But if I manage to get around #1, I almost inevitably will face #2.

Comment: Taking a step back, it's an interaction problem between Google and StackOverflow. How should a webpage indicate that it is not a resource by itself, but a collection of weakly related snippets? Meaning that Google should index each snippet separately?

Comment: What's wrong with just not clicking question list links from Google anymore?

Comment: @MSalters: There appears to be a crawler instruction for exactly that case: [`<META NAME=”ROBOTS” CONTENT=”NOINDEX, FOLLOW”>`](http://dan-nolan.com/what-is-noindex/)  [Google supports it](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag?hl=en)

Comment: I've noticed lately that Google has started giving me SO pages where *most* of my keywords are in the question or answer, but some are only in the "Related" or "Hot Network Questions" links at the side.

Answer (score 15):

If I simply add `stackoverflow` to your Google query

```
stackoverflow Allman style jscs
```

the first link I got listed is a particular Q&A [Dangerous implications of Allman style in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247328/dangerous-implications-of-allman-style-in-javascript)

The search could certainly improved, e.g. by excluding java-script or so.

But in general I agree with you, that Google links shown for the *newest* tab aren't really helpful.

Comment: The question you found doesn't even mention JSCS, but it's another Google issue.

Comment: Your example using advanced operators could be a google for `Allman style jscs -"page * stack overflow" site:stackoverflow.com/questions`

Comment: If you want the results of your search to always include a search term, preface it with `+` so in your case, probably `+Allman style +jscs`. Now that doesn't actually return any results with both `Allman` and `jscs`, but that's how'd you get results, if there were any :)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The + advanced operator was removed from Google search when Google+ wanted to take it over for name tagging. Use quotes instead.

Answer (score 7):

These results come up on very selective queries, I don't think Google ranks the pages too highly.  When the same terms appear within a single question, the question is ranked first.  I don't think there's a real problem.

Additionally, if these pages were delisted, they would be overtaken by equivalent indexes from the clones.

Comment: Google does rank them highly. It usually puts them on the first page because SO itself is ranked high. And there is no fully equivalent indexes on the clones as these pages are constantly and fast changing in a quasirandom way.

Comment: Of course, I agree that there is no big problem. Just an annoying resemblance to black-hat SEO and its Markov chain-based keyword stuffing techniques.

Answer (score 7):

It can be done on the client side.

If you notice a pattern of undesirable results in your Google queries, you can exclude them with the "URL does not contain" (`-inurl:`) operator. For example, you can exclude question list pages on Stack Exchange sites with `Allman style jscs -inurl:/questions/tagged/`. This method should be familiar to people who were around before Stack Overflow was so highly ranked, having to add `-site:experts-exchange.com` or `-site:jstor.org` on specific queries in order not to get flooded with paywalled crap.

Answer (score 1):

An example of #1 useless results are:

- Recently Active Questions - Page 79783
- Unanswered Questions - Page 16641
- Hot 'javascript' Questions - Page 17559

because the page has changed since it was indexed (so that clicking on the link takes you to a page that doesn't contain the search terms).

Dynamic lists such as the above should be marked to not be indexed to avoid stale indexing of pages by external search engines e.g. by using `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` in the markup.

Ideally mark pages 2 to ∞ as non-indexed, since page 1 could be exactly what the user is looking for (e.g. a search for `hot javascript questions` should probably return Page 1).

Answer (score 0):

For a workaround, you can [refine the Google](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314682/436776) search terms to remove junk paginated list results by using [advanced operators](http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference.html):

-"page * stack overflow" site:stackoverflow.com/questions

A feature to remove "junk" pages from indexing is still required, since the vast majority of searchers won't know to use those terms.